# why Nothing is shown in ng-repeat?

Tags: html, angularjs, json

now i have spring service which return arraylist .. I made an allert to test the array which is returned in controller and it is appeared successfully as a JSON objects .. but Nothing is shown in ng repeat in Html File

HTML File :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="phase2">

<head>
<title>Student Page</title>
<script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script data-semver="1.2.28" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.28/angular.js" data-require="angular.js@1.2.x"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.28/angular-route.js"></script>
 <script src="LogInController.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div ng-app="phase2" >
 <div ng-controller="load" >
  <tr ng-repeat="x in sharedData">
   <td> {{x.name}} </td> 
   <td> => {{x.score}} </td>
  </tr>
  
 </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

LogInController.js :

```js
var app = angular.module("phase2" , ['ngRoute'])

app.config(["$routeProvider", "$locationProvider", function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
    $routeProvider
  .when("http://localhost:8060/TheAngular_Project/LogInPage.html", {
   templateUrl: "LogInPage.html",
   controller: "LogIn"
  })
  .when("http://localhost:8060/TheAngular_Project/StudentPage.html", {
   templateUrl: "StudentPage.html",
   controller: "load"
  })
  .when("http://localhost:8060/TheAngular_Project/TeacherPage.html", {
   templateUrl: "TeacherPage.html",
   controller: "load"
  })
  // .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/'})
  ;
}]);

app.controller( "LogIn" ,function ($scope , $http , srvShareData , $location)
  {
   $scope.dataToShare = [];
   $scope.save = function() {
    var email= document.getElementById("email").value;
    var Pass=document.getElementById("Pass").value;
    var Info ;
    $http.get('http://localhost:8090/LogIn/'+email+'/'+Pass)
    .then(function(response)
     {
      Info = JSON.stringify(response.data);
      $scope.dataToShare = Info ;
      srvShareData.addData($scope.dataToShare);
      //$scope.day=srvShareData.getData();
      if ($scope.dataToShare.schema)
       {
       window.location.href="http://localhost:8060/TheAngular_Project/TeacherPage.html";
       }
      else
       {
       window.location.href="http://localhost:8060/TheAngular_Project/StudentPage.html";
       }
     });
    }
  });

app.controller("load" , function($scope,  srvShareData )
 {
 
   $scope.sharedData = srvShareData.getData();
   alert($scope.sharedData)
 });


app.service('srvShareData', function($window) {
    var KEY = 'App.SelectedValue';

    var addData = function(newObj) {
     //$window.sessionStorage.clear();
        var mydata = $window.sessionStorage.getItem(KEY);
        if (mydata) {
            mydata = JSON.parse(mydata);
        } else {
            mydata = [];
        }
        mydata = newObj;
       
        $window.sessionStorage.setItem(KEY, JSON.stringify(mydata));
    };

    var getData = function(){
        var mydata = $window.sessionStorage.getItem(KEY);
        if (mydata) {
            mydata = JSON.parse(mydata);
        }
        
        return mydata || [];
    };

    return {
        addData: addData,
        getData: getData
    };
});
```

Comment: post what you have inside sharedData?

Comment: @Pengyy its already there

Comment: SharedData
[{"name":"Subtraction","scienceCategory":null,"schema":null,"score":1500}]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some changes in html and its working fine for me (Also you don't have to use `ng-app` again):

**HTML:**

```
<body ng-controller="mainCtrl" class="container" style="padding-top:30px">
    <table>
      <tr ng-repeat="x in sharedData">
        <td> {{x.name}} </td>
        <td> => {{x.score}} </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
```

**Script:**

```
angular.module('app', []);

angular.module('app').controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.sharedData = [{
    name: 'Subtraction',
    score: 1500
  }]

});
```

And here is the working Plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/I1mfsgJfgsw1b92lJCkO?p=preview